# Why can't I browse network shares on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba, file-sharing

This is driving me nuts. I recently did a fresh install of 12.04 on three computers (two laptops, one desktop). For a while, I was able to connect to my FreeNAS media server through Browse Network, but the connection would timeout after a while and the only way to mount the device again was after a reboot.

Things get more confusing. I wanted to share folders on the computers and was prompted to install Samba, which I did on one laptop and the desktop. That enabled me to see the two computers in Browse Network, but I wasn't able to mount the shared folders (yes, they were definitely shared).

After some research, I thought installing `cifs-utils` would help, which I did on the computers with shared folders; however, after installation I could no longer see the computers through Browse Network. I removed the application and also removed Samba on the desktop. The result: I can see my FreeNAS server but not connect to it at all even after a reboot, but suddenly I am able to mount the shared folder from my laptop, which I didn't except after removing Samba.

I never had any of these issues with 11.04, which is what I was using before installing the LTS. I could easily navigate shared folders and my FreeNAS, and never had any problems remounting a device any time during a single working session.

I know the FreeNAS box is connected to my network, because I use it with wireless media players. So what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Nautilus?

Try Go -> Location and type

smb://machinename.its.domain/share-name/

and if you want save it as bookmark

Hope it helps